# adding ssh key to Git account

Tags: git, ssh

I generate a new ssh key and I try to add in my Git account 
I follow the steps in this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/)

In the last phase when generating a new ssh key, I try to add the new ssh to the ssh-agent using this code

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have an error like

> $ ssh-add ~/ .ssh/id_rsa
>   Error loading key "/c/Users/hp/": Is a directory
>   .ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment. As it seems you're using NIX commands on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in your command in the quote, which should not be there:

```
ssh-add ~/ .ssh/id_rsa
```

The path should be without a space:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```